# HashMap Not Calling Object.equals?

Tags: java, object, collections, hashmap

I wrote a class that overrides the equals(Object) method in class Object to compare objects of the class type to other objects of a class type using the object's instance values.

When I put an instance of the object in a HashMap as the key, and then call get(Object) on the map with a new but identical object as the key, it returns null.

I've tried passing a new, identical object to the equals method and it returns true, so the problem isn't my comparison code.

From what I've gathered through debugging, the equals(Object) method in my object is never called.

But if you use a String key in a HashMap and then pass a new instance with identical characters to get(Object), it returns the value successfully.

Why is this happening?  What do I have to do to have HashMap test keys based on MY equals method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to also override [`Object.hashcode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).  Take a look at the link, as it specifies that `hashcode()` and `equals()` have a contract to ensure proper functionality in `HashTable`'s, `HashMap`'s, and `HashSet`'s.

In a `HashMap`, values are stored in buckets, which are reached by the hashcode of the key.  Once the proper bucket is found, the equals method is then applied to each member of the bucket until equality is determined.  Because of this, it is important to make sure that your hash algorithm 'hashes well'.

Comment: So hashCode() should return identical integers if equals() is true?

Comment: Correct.  It is best practice to write your hashing algorithm using the same members that `equals` uses to find equality.

Comment: Does it matter what the integer is?  Hashtables use powers of two for capacity and load factor correct?

Comment: The integer does not matter.  It is just preferable that your hashing is diverse (very likely to end up in different buckets) to reduce the number of calls to `equals` that must be made.

Comment: But what should the algorithm really do?  How do we prevent a call to a non-equal object accidentally through random chance returning the same integer?

Comment: Hashing is just how it finds the bucket.  Not everything in the bucket is going to be equal.  That is why it is best to find the 'best hashing algorithm', because after it finds the right bucket, it is going to have to find the right element (by calling `equals()` until it finds it or runs out of elements).

Answer (score 1):

You should also override hashCode otherwise it won't work as HashMap (as the name suggests) equates equality based on a collection of hashes. The Java "honour code" for overriding equals is that you should also override hashCode at the same time.