# Why is equals method not called in the Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;
class Dog {
    public Dog(String n) { name = n; }
    public String name;
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("equals called..");
        if((o instanceof Dog) &&
                (((Dog)o).name == name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("hashCodecalled..");
        return name.length(); 
    }
}
class SampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object, String> m = new HashMap<Object, String>();
        Dog d1 = new Dog("clover");
        m.put(d1, "Dog key");
        d1.name ="arthur";
        System.out.println(m.get(d1));      
    }
}
```

In the above code, the output i get is:

```
hashCodecalled..
hashCodecalled..
Dog key
```

after i do d1.name ="arthur"

i was expecting output to be

```
hashCodecalled..``
hashCodecalled..
equals called..
null
```

Comment: You can't change an object after you use it as a map key. Java certainly won't detect and rehash.

Comment: In this case it actually *doesn't* change the hash value, because `hashCode` returns the name's length and "arthur" is the same length as "clover".  But this is still a strange and error-prone thing to do, and it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Wyzard: i was just tying to check if i change the key but key the same hash code, whether equals method is called. And whether equals method correctly differentiates the new string from the old one.

Comment: Well, you haven't really changed the key, because it's still the same `Dog` object.  Even if your `equals` were called, it'd just be comparing that single object with itself — effectively doing `d1.equals(d1)`.  That's always going to return true, regardless of what the name is.

Answer (score 8):

Since the `HashMap` has the exact object that you're looking for, it doesn't need to call `equals` to verify that the object is the right one.

When you `get` an object from a `HashMap`, first the `hashCode` is evaluated to find the right bucket.  Then, the bucket is searched.  But each key in the bucket is compared first using `==`.  If the object is not the one that is being sought, then `equals` is used.

In Java 7, the key part of the code, in the `get` method of `HashMap` is

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
    return e.value;
```

Comment: +1 and for to not null value, it is because hashcode hasn't changed because of length = 6

Comment: True.  If the dog's name had changed to something with a different number of letters, the `HashMap` would be unable to find the key.

Answer (score 2):

[This question has been asked before in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919941/hashmap-not-calling-object-equals)

According to the hashCode method, it states "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." In general, whenever you create your equals method, make sure it is consistent to the returning hashcode value.

The HashMap will always compare the objects using the hashCode before the equal method. For your case if you would like to see the equal method to be invoked, you can simulate the hash collision scenario by just making the hashcode value to be a constant. (Caveat: This is not a bad example as it impacts a lot in term of performance.)

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Object, String> m = new HashMap<Object, String>();
    Dog d1 = new Dog("clover");
    Dog d2 = new Dog("clover 2");
    m.put(d1, "Dog 1");
    m.put(d2, "Dog 2");
    System.out.println(m.get(d1)); 
}

class Dog {
private String name;
public Dog(String n) {   
    name = n; 
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    System.out.println("equals called..");
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("hashCodecalled..");
    return 1; // constant
}}
```

and the result:

hashCodecalled..

hashCodecalled..

equals called..

hashCodecalled..

Dog 2

And finally of course you need to insert at least two object to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

See the java.util.HashMap.get method code.

It first check if the key == e.key then check key.equals(e.key).

In your code, you are passing the same instance to the get method.
So key == e.key. and key.equals(e.key) won't be executed.

```
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
      e != null;
      e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But, I have changed the key here to "arthur"

Comment: No, the key is the `Dog`.

Comment: Even if you change a field of instance d1, it is still d1. And you are passing d1 which is exactly same instance stored in the hash map.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code of HashMap, it check for null first, because the hashcode not changed(length of name doesn't change), and then == is compared (as David say). It is true and equals() won't check ,so it return that Dog.

```
 public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### David Wallace has provided simple to the point answer

#### Mine is explaination of HashMap working in bit detail, So it might help others.

In HashMap the objects are stored in groups called buckets (of keys). All the key objects that have same hashCode value are stored in one bucket. So,for example `Dog k1 = new Dog("clover")` , `Dog k2 = new Dog("clever")` and `Dog k3 = new Dog("123456");` are all stored in one bucket due to the `hashCode()` method of `Dog` returns length of name as hashCode value. All 3 Dog objects names here are of length 6, hence go into one bucket.

When `get()` method is called, the `HashMap` locates the bucket with same hashCode of the given key, if found then on each of the object in bucket it first uses simple == equality check to see if given key and object in bucket are same objects, if not then `equals()` method equality check to find for exact object.

So, if the key object content is changed after a key (Dog object) is used to store (put) the key-value pair into the HashMap, it may not be possible find/retreive the original object (sometimes it may). Let us see how.

#### Scenario 1:

For example if the `Dog k3` `name` is changed to "1234", then the hashCode would now become 4. Assuming only k1, k2 and k3 are put into the HashMap, when `get(k3)` is called (now having name "1234") will result in looking for a bucket that holds objects with hashCode 4. Due to only one bucket that holds objects with hashCodes of 6 and no bucket of hashCode of 4, it results in no bucket found and no attempt will be made to use equals() method.

When I come searching for "you" using home your address, if I cannot find your home in first place, There is no question of compare names of household members.

The get() method here returns null. This is the case of corrupted entry which can never be retrieved, unless the key content is changed again to bring its hashCode value back to 6.

#### Scenario 2:

But if `k3` `name` is changed to "654321" which is of length 6, then the bucket will be found and the equals() will be called to compare with 3 object that were put in the bucket, and also the equals() returns true for one object that is same k3. Remember here the same object k3 which was used to put is changed, so the change reflects in HashMap also, it is the same one object. Here the == equality check succeeds for k3 and equals() method is not called (this bit is picked up from David Wallace answer, any up votes on this point please give him not me!). The result of get() method here will be the expected non-null object. It is because the change in key content preserved the hashCode value of 6.

#### Scenario 3:

Now if we take a separate `Dog k4 = new Dog("123456");` and also change `k3.name` to `"654321"`. Guess what happens when `get(k4)` is called ! The bucket will be located and  == fails due to the given key is a separate object, then equals is also called on all 3 objects in map bucket but equals fails and final result of get(k4) is `false`. Because the object k3.name change affects key stored in the map bucket to change from "123456" to "654321". When asked to find for "123456", there is no key matching "123456", though was originally put with that value it is now "654321" in the map.

Hence it is not safe to change the key objects content after used to store in map. The same applies to HashSet a Set implementation that also uses the same hashing. Infact, HashSet uses HashMap behind the scene.

### Why does it behave like that

For better performance. If no bucketing is used, then everytime a new entry is put it has to compare with all existing (previously put) objects to ensure uniqueness. Also while existing entry is retrieved (get() called) it has to compare with all the objects in the HashMap until it finds a match. Using the bucketing as above it can safely ignore some of the entries/objects to compare for equality.

To support this mechanism used in Hash implementations, there is specification/contract between the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods that should be followed when implementing those method for objects that can be used for storing in Hash based implementations. [JavaDoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), have a read.

PS : I picked up the == check before equals() part from David Wallace answer and edited into here. Thank you David for your comment.

Comment: Very thorough.  Not quite correct - see my answer.  Also, this doesn't actually answer the question.  OP wants to know why `equals` isn't called in this case.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I see what you mean. You are right. I missed the == check before equals() check part in the explanation. You can go ahead and edit my answer to include that or let me add your details here, so will help others Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why would I edit your answer, when I have already provided my own?

Comment: Alright, no worries. I will add it to the explanation, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `hashCode` is based on the length of the `name` `String` and both the values you've used have a length of 6.

Also `HashMap` has an optimization where it performs reference equality before using `equals()`. Here it won't need to use `equals` because it's the same key object.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object as a hash key, you should make it [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html). Changing an object used as a hash key causes unexpected behavior, as you have seen, and being immutable means you can't change the object after it's been created.

Comment: This is a bit too broad.  It's OK for an object used as a key to have mutable fields, so long as those fields aren't used by the `equals` or `hashCode` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must use use immutable classes (e.g. `String` or wrapper classes) as the key of `Map`, otherwise there will be inconsistency in the flow of how Map works (because of its hashing algorithm).

You can make a Custom class (e.g. `Dog`) immutable so later you cannot change the key you have used.

It is like you are locking a door with a key and later you changed the same key by some "tools" and then expecting to open the locked door.